# Load external script on ng-switch-when

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to load an external script only when `ng-switch-when` is a specific number? *For example in a structure like so, is it possible to load an external script when the `step = 3`?:*

```
<div ng-switch="step"> 
   <div ng-switch-when="1">
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="2">
   </div>
   <div ng-switch-when="3">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OcLazyLoad is an angular module that is specially designed for loading the file on demand.
[ocLazy laod](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)

Call your controller function with the help of ng-init directive.

```
<div ng-switch-when="3" ng-init="laodFile()">
```

```
    $scope.loadFile = function($ocLazyLoad) {
     $ocLazyLoad.load('testModule.js');
}
```

Note : - Don't forget to inject oclazyload module before using.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, unfortunately this doesn't work for me

Comment: have u read documentation of oclazylaod ? There are many ways to load files.

Comment: I went through them yes, if eventually I find a way to do this with ozlazyload, I will accept the answer.

Comment: ok cool. there is one more module with pure java script. https://github.com/krux/postscribe . hope oclazyload  will solve your problem